# Swift - minimumLineSpacing in UICollectionViewLayout to adjust the space between rows

Tags: ios, swift

According to Apple's documentation minimumLineSpacing from the UICollectionFlowLayout class should determine the amount of spacing between two rows within your UICollectionView.

I've subclassed the UICollectionFlowLayout and connected that class to my UICollectionView. However, no matter what value I set minimumLineSpacing to I have no effect to the look of the CollectionView.

How do I set the space in-between rows?

```
// My subclassed UICollectionViewFlowLayout
import UIKit

class CustomImageFlowLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout{

    override init(){
        super.init()
        setupLayout()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init()
        setupLayout()
    }

    func setupLayout(){
        self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1 // <-- this works just fine
        self.minimumLineSpacing = 55 // <-- no matter what this value is nothing changes.
        scrollDirection = .Vertical
    }

    override var itemSize: CGSize{
        set{

        }

        get{
            let numberOfColumns: CGFloat = 3

            let itemWidth = (CGRectGetWidth(self.collectionView!.frame) - (numberOfColumns - 1)) / numberOfColumns
            return CGSizeMake(itemWidth, itemWidth)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` is designed to be subclassed. I can think of some reasons why the way you're overriding `itemSize` might cause an issue. Why don't you just create a plain old `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and set its properties, or coordinate with its `delegate`, as the class is designed to work?

Comment: I tried your recommendation but I got the exact same result. Why is it not recommended to subclass UiCollectionFlowLayout?

Comment: The docs aren't specific, but they do describe it as "concrete" vs. "abstract". They also don't show any "subclassing notes" which are common to see in other classes. Can you update your question with your new approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below function within your `UICollectionViewDelegate`

**SWIFT**

```
optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat
```

**OBJECTIVE-C**

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
```